# Estimation of Gumbel copula in R failing

Tags: r, statistics, finance

As per the title, I'm having an issue with estimating copulas in R. For this I need to use the [copula](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/copula/versions/0.99-0) package.
I have the log returns of assets $GM, $AAPL and $MSFT. I need to estimate the copula using MLE. It would seem that for this I need to use the `fitCopula` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/copula/versions/0.99-0/topics/fitCopula).

The code I have is the following:

```
library(quantmod)
library(copula)

# data
getSymbols(c("GM", "AAPL","MSFT"), src = "yahoo",  from = "2009-01-01")
mydata=data.frame(na.omit(diff(log(merge(Ad(GM),Ad(AAPL),Ad(MSFT))))))
cor(mydata)
# Define the number of observations
(n <- nrow(mydata))
   
# Transform the data to uniform margins
u =sapply(mydata, function(x){
  ecx=ecdf(x)
  ecx(x)
  })
plot(data.frame(u))

# A Gumbel copula
   
# Maximum likelihood estimation 2 assets ("GM", "AAPL")
fit.ml2 <- fitCopula(gumbelCopula(dim=2), u[,1:2], method="ml", start = 3)
summary(fit.ml2)

# Maximum likelihood estimation 2 assets ("AAPL","MSFT")
fit.ml2a <- fitCopula(gumbelCopula(dim=2), u[,c(2:3)], method="ml", start = 3)
summary(fit.ml2a)

# Maximum likelihood estimation 3 assets
fit.ml3 <- fitCopula(gumbelCopula(dim=3), u, method="ml", start = 3)
summary(fit.ml3)
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Warning message:
In fitCopula.ml(copula, u = data, method = method, start = start,  :
  Hessian matrix not invertible: Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
```

According to ChatGPT,  this can be caused by various factors, such as:

- **Lack of fit:** The chosen copula may not be appropriate for the data, and the resulting parameter estimates may be inaccurate or unreliable.
- **Small sample size:** When the sample size is small, the maximum likelihood estimates may be imprecise, and the optimization algorithm may fail to converge.
- **Correlation structure:** The copula parameter estimates can be affected by the correlation structure of the data. If the data has high correlation or dependence, the optimization algorithm may have difficulty finding a suitable solution

However:

- I've trialled a variety of different `start` (theta) parameters;
- The chosen copula should be right one, according to a different package ([VineCopula](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VineCopula/versions/2.4.5));
- I have more than 3,000 observations;
- The linear correlation between the two assets is 0.38, 0.40 and 0.60.

I suppose there may be something I am not understanding not only about the copula library but also about the underlying statistical theory.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share your data, if possible?